# Как из Fragment перейти в другой класс при помощи Intent ?

Tags: android-fragment, android, android-intent

В Fragment я сделал кнопку, обработчик нажатия и с помощью Intent хочу перейти в  класс Karta, но не получается.
Eclipse ругается The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Karta>) is undefined

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,
                container, false);

        button1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (this,Karta.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});

        return rootView;

    }

}

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Karta extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.karta);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Код класса Karta покажите что ли.

Comment: Он в принципе пустой...

Comment: а в манифесте ты добавить Karta не забыл часом?

Comment: нет не забыл.

Comment: Вот правильный ответ
 Intent intent = new Intent(Fragment1.this.getActivity(),Karta.class);

Comment: Можно просто:

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Karta.class);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл в том, что this во фрагменте

`public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (this,Karta.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }`

ссылается на интерфейс OnClickListener, в котором нет реализации класса Context
поэтому правильным будет уже приведенный в комментарии ответ

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Fragment1.this.getActivity(),Karta.class);
```